# disable bios unlock/reset after setting a password

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, passwords

I found some easy methods to unlock/reset bios password if you forgot it. 
like type the wrong password 3 times and then you get some number and enter it in a web page, which generates a password to log in with.

is there a way to prevent that? I want to lock bios and stop other users for sure not getting in to make any changes. that could be dangerous if they get into bios make boot from USB or sth...

does anyone have a suggestion on how to secure bios/boot?

Comment: Short answer, no you cannot prevent bios being unlocked by known tricks, buy a laptop that does not have one of those weaknesses.

Comment: can u give me a hint about such a laptop or computer that hasn't such weakness, i need to prevent unlocking bios and prevent sb to boot computer. i read also about the bios chip, that u can change but i still have no real solution

Comment: Lenovo is one suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Through the BIOS menu, you can set and change an Administrator password,
sometimes called also Supervisor password.

By setting an Administrator password, you will prevent other users from changing
your BIOS settings, as this password will be needed to enter the BIOS.

The Administrator password is different from the BIOS password, since it is not
required for booting the computer, only for modifying the BIOS.

Warning: Never set the two BIOS passwords, Administrator and User, to be the same.
You risk to never again be able to modify the BIOS.

[image]

Comment: well i guess people may also be able to unlock this one though and i am looking to prevent users from booting computer

Comment: There is no defense against a knowledgeable user that has physical access to the computer and can boot it. Taking out the hard disk is the only sure defense.

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem

As noted, the BIOS can be reset with removal of the CMOS battery, or using the jumper method to reset the BIOS, which is found in most motherboards. I have never heard of a password reset through a web page, but that would be a problem.

Here is an FAQ article from ASUS on how to reset the BIOS on most of their motherboards: https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1030210/ It talks about the two-pin jumper method, BIOS reset buttons that exist on some motherboards, and the battery removal method.

### A Potential Solution

What must be done is physical measures to secure the desktop and its internal components. There are desktop chassis security screws to lock the case closed. There are also locked cabinet systems for more serious security needs. That would prevent individuals from resetting the BIOS if you already have a password on it. Do a search for "desktop chassis security" to find some options.

In the case of a reset password method on the BIOS, there are ways to skip the BIOS splash screen and boot right into your operating system, but I believe the user could still enter the right hotkeys to enter the BIOS. I would suggest getting a different motherboard that does not have a BIOS reset password option.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).